# I need help understanding this algorithm solution of Top k frequent element

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am having trouble understanding the last line of this algorithm specifically the inside of the sort method, I don't understand why `b[1]` is being subtracted by `a[1]` I tried working through the return statement one step at a time: I know that at `Object.entries(storage)` I should have an array with 3 arrays inside like so `[[1,4],[3,3],[2,1]]` I then console logged `b[1]` to see what it would be and it gave me 4 from the first array and 3 from the second array then I console logged `a[1]` and the output was 3 from the second array and 2 from the third array so I'm really confused as to why they don't even start from the same index which would be `[1]`. If I'm not clear or if I'm missing any information let me know and I will try to update my question quickly

The testcase I'm using is `nums=[1,1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2]` and `k=2`

[the original question in leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/description/)

```
var topKFrequent = (nums, k) => {
let storage = {}
for(let num of nums){
    
    storage[num] = (storage[num] ?? 0) + 1
    console.log(storage[num],'tset')
    
}
return Object.entries(storage).sort((a,b) => b[1] -a[1]).map(val=>Number(val[0])).slice(0,k);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, given `[[1,4],[3,3],[2,1]]`, it first compares `a = [3,3]` with `b = [1,4]`. Your *"same index"*  sounds like you expect it to compare `[1,4]` with itself? Anyway, `b[1] - a[1]` = 4-3 = 1 is *greater* than zero. The sorting algorithm really is ascending, so "greater" means "belongs on the right". So you're telling it that `[3,3]` belongs to the right of `[1,4]`.

In the second comparison, you're telling it that `[2,1]` belongs to the right of `[3,3]`.

That's all the sorter needs to know. The only possible order is `[[1,4],[3,3],[2,1]]`.

After that, the `map` extracts the first number of each pair: `[1,3,2]`. And then the `slice` gives you the first `k` of those, e.g., `[1,3]` if k=2.

Comment: but wouldn't b=[1,4] be b[0], it makes sense that a[1] is [3,3]

Comment: Hmm, none of that makes sense. If b is [1,4], then b[0] is 1, not b itself. More generally, if b=[x,y], then b[0]=x.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm really confused as to why they don't even start from the same index which would be [1]

The `sort` method decides "on its own" which two values (two little subarrays in this case -- I will refer to them as "elements") from the input array it will pass as arguments to your callback function. We are not supposed to be concerned by that choice.

Realise that the internal sort algorithm will call your callback function when it wants to know how two elements from the given array compare.

It is normal that this internal sort algorithm will select `a` and `b` as two *different* elements, as it doesn't need to know how the first element compares *with itself*. It needs to know how two *distinct* elements compare and for that it will call your callback function. `a` and `b` could really be elements at any index in your array, and in subsequent calls of the callback those indices don't have to follow a certain order. It really could be any pair from the array depending on which algorithm the `sort` method uses. It could in theory even decide to start with the last two elements in your array...

Although we could dive into the source code of the JavaScript engine we are working with (like V8) to determine what `a` and `b` would be when the callback is called, it really shouldn't be of our concern. All we are responsible for is to have the callback answer the question how the given `a` and `b` compare.

We do this by:

- returning 0 when we want `a` and `b` to be treated as equal in the sorting order,
- returning a negative number when we want `a` to be ordered before `b` in the result (we define that `a` is "less than" `b`)
- returning a positive number when we want `a` to be ordered after `b` in the result (we define that `a` is "greater than" `b`).

As long as the sorting algorithm doesn't have enough information to complete the sort, it will call the callback to get more info. All the rest of the sorting algorithm is taken care of by the `sort` method implementation.

Comment: Excellent, that's what I meant. What I meant would actually be clearer if they were just sorting frequencies, i.e., if they sorted by `b - a`. Then with your previous *"a negative number when a is less than b"*, a beginner would see the code and think "No, `b - a` is negative if a is *larger* than b." Now it's clear. I might just add the mnemonic of zero as reference, that "less than" appears both in "a is less than b" as well as in "negative is less than zero", and likewise for the other two cases. I.e., I think of it as *"If I want to consider a less than b, return a number less than 0"*.

Answer (score 0):

The part after `=>` and before the `)` is your compare function. In your case:

```
b[1] - a[1]
```

Subtracting your sort values `(a,b)` makes sort compare numbers instead of strings. The sort order (ascending/descending) depends on comparing b subtracted from a **or** a from b. Your function assumes there are no Infinity or NaN in the array.

Comment: The default for JavaScript without a function is Unicode sorting.